# Using Discord Webhooks to Send a Message with Embedded Image Files Using urllib3 Requests in Python

Tags: python, http, discord, discord.py

I am trying to use Discord Webhooks to send a message to a channel in my Discord server using Python that utilizes the embed system to have a title, description, and image without sending multiple messages. I am trying to do this using the urllib3 library. Ideally I would like to be able to send an image that gets put in embed as can be seen [here](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/img/webhook_example.png)

At the current moment I am able to send a request that has an embed with a title and description but no image. The code below is what I am using to accomplish that.

```
json_data = {
    "content": "Hello World",
    "embeds": [
        {
            "title": "Image Name",
            "description": "Image Description",
            "image": {
                "url": "attachment://image.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}

request = HTTP.request("POST",
    url=WEBHOOK_URL,
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Content-Disposition": "form-data"},
    body=json.dumps(json_data),
    timeout=urllib3.Timeout(10))

print(request.data)
```

This causes the following message to be sent to the discord server and gives a console output of b''.

[Image of Discord server with a embed message featuring a Title and Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kGXw.png)

I have tried using the following code to accomplish this using the attachments but I know that I need to upload the files as stated in [the Discord developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files) but I cannot figure out how I am supposed to accomplish that.

```
with open("image.jpg", "rb") as f:
   image_file = f.read()
   json_data = {
      "content": "Hello World",
      "embeds": [
         {
            "title": "Image Name",
            "description": "Image Description",
            "image": {
               "url": "attachment://image.jpg"
            }
         }
      ],
      "attachments": [
         {
            "id": 0,
            "description": "Image description",
            "filename": "image.jpg"
         }
      ]
   }

   request = HTTP.request("POST",
      url=WEBHOOK_URL,
      headers={"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", "Content-Disposition": "form-data"},
      body=json.dumps(json_data),
      timeout=urllib3.Timeout(10))

   print(request.data)
```

When the code above is ran it results in the following output.

```
b'{"attachments": ["0"]}'
```

I know that I can upload and send an image outside of the embed but I cannot figure out how to send an image within an embed. The following code has worked for sending an image but will not embed it and just attaches an image to the message.

```
with open("image.png", "rb") as f:
    file = f.read()
    payload={
        'content': 'Here is a picture',
        'attachment':('image.png',file,'text/png')
    }
    request = HTTP.request("POST",url=WEBHOOK,headers={"Content-Disposition": "form-data"},
        fields=payload,timeout=urllib3.Timeout(10))
```

I understand that I could simply use the Python library discord-webhook however I am trying to learn more about HTTP requests as there is clearly a gap in my knowledge somewhere. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

I had to put the standard json body inside of the payload using "payload_json" and that properly uploaded the image and then embedded it.

The following code is what worked for me.

```
with open("image.jpg", "rb") as f:
        file = f.read()
        payload_data = {
            "content":"",
            "attachment": ("image.jpg", file, "text/jpg"),
            "payload_json": (None, json.dumps({
                    "content": "",
                    "embeds": [
                        {
                            "title": "EMBED TITLE",
                            "description": "EMBED DESCRIPTION",
                            "image": {
                                "url": "attachment://image.jpg"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }))
        }
        request = HTTP.request("POST",
            url=WEBHOOK_URL,
            headers={"Content-Disposition": "form-data"},
            fields=payload_data,
            timeout=urllib3.Timeout(10))
```

The output in Discord looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBh5N.png), which is what I was looking for.